# Code is working fine in chrome, but not in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have some code here. That is working fine in Chrome, but not in IE and Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumb").click(function(){
        alert ("Reached here.");
        var cat_id = $(this).attr('id'); // get category id
        alert (cat_id);

    });
});


<a href="#" class="thumb" id = "20" name="df" >
    <img src="images/dry_fruits.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
</a>
```

Its even not hitting the alert in Firefox and IE. Can someone please help me to identify the issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Devesh

Comment: Have you checked that the document.ready have not already fired in these browsers? i.e `if($(document).isReady){alert('already ready')}`

Comment: Are you sure that the $(document).ready() function is firing at all in those browsers?

Comment: 1) Can you update your question to include a full HTML file? 
2) You are including jQuery in your HTML file, right?

Comment: @mariusnn if the dom is already loaded `$(document).ready` calls the function immediately.

Comment: @Musa - I've had issues - especially when handling dynamically added content - where I've experienced that $(document).ready(..) never triggers (from my reasoning due to pageLoad already being fired)

Comment: @dja Yes. I am including JQuery in HTML file only. I think i can not include full HTML file as its a big file around 2000 LOC, that's why i have given code snippet.

Comment: Is that HTML dynamically generated?

Comment: Working fine in FF and IE. http://jsfiddle.net/PKy2w/. Is this anchor elements are dynamically generated?

Comment: @mariusnn , you are right. i was using $(document).ready(function() check multiple times in my HTML file. That was causing the issue. Only one time check makes everything work fine. Can you please make that as answer so i can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping everything to be done together in one call to `$(document).ready` ensures no problems with race-conditions etc in which order the functions added are called.

If one function adds the element to the DOM and another require its presence you might get conflicts and unexpected behavior due to varying calling order...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug with jQuery 2.0.2. I fiddled it and IE threw errors on just the $(document).ready().

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied. jquery-2.0.2.js, line 1378 character 2
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined _display, line 21 character 1
```

Swapped the jQuery version to 1.9.1 and everything worked fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/taneleero/pLRNF/3/

Comment: It should be already fixed because it's working for me with jQuery 2.x (edge).

Comment: I noticed that also, but looked odd enough to take a shot at the anwser.